# Is there a formula I can use to fetch cell data using data from a row header and the minimum value from a range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I want the data that shows up in Column D to be fetch based on the data in column A. Right now the match formula is calling to a specific range, but I would like it to change based on the data in column A.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rENXR.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FS58z.png)

I've tried various formulas and right now I'm using this one temporarily:

`=INDEX(Groceries!$B$1:$H$33, 1, MATCH(MIN(Groceries!B10:H10),Groceries!B10:H10,0))`

Basically I need a formula that looks at a cell in column A in "Food Inventory", and uses that to find the appropriate row in "Groceries". Then finds the minimum in the range B-H, and uses that to find the column header of that minimum.

For example: "Eggs" in cell A4 in "Food Inventory" would lead you to "Eggs" row in "Groceries". The formula would then find the minimum value of range  B12:H12. With cell C12 being the minimum value, the formula would then look at the header in Row 1 and ultimately report cell C1 from "Groceries" in cell D4 in "Food Inventory".

I may already know the individual formulas to make this work, but I'm really having a brain block on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XLOOKUP to find the minimum value and its respective position in another range. With INDEX and XMATCH you find the row of the product, and with BYROW you repeat the process through each element. I reduced the sample, but you can see it working:

```
=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(a,IF(a="","",XLOOKUP(0,INDEX(Groceries!B:Z,XMATCH(a,Groceries!A:A)),Groceries!B1:1,,1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm. Because this list is getting resorted often, I had to switch A2:A to A2 and apply it to each row. Thanks a bunch!